# JavaScript - sort 2 object arrays on the same field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In JavaScript I have 2 object arrays that have the same objects but are in a different order.  I'm trying to figure out how to sort one array based on the order of the other.  There is a unique field they both share (sortField below) I'm just failing on figuring out how to sort with it.  Here's an example of my arrays:

sorter array:

```
[
  {
    "displayName": "Party",
    "sortField": "com.uniqueXbd",
    "elementId": "PtyListPanel"
  }, {
    "displayName": "Group",
    "sortField": "com.uniqueARd",
    "elementId": "GrpListPaneARd"
  }, {
    "displayName": "Leader",
    "sortField": "com.uniqueEcF",
    "elementId": "LeaderListPaneEcF"
  }
]
```

needsSorted array:

```
[
  {
    "displayName": "Group",
    "sortField": "com.uniqueARd",
    "elementId": "GrpListPaneARd"
  }, {
    "displayName": "Leader",
    "sortField": "com.uniqueEcF",
    "elementId": "LeaderListPanel"
  }, {
    "displayName": "Party",
    "sortField": "com.uniqueXbd",
    "elementId": "PtyListPaneEcF"
  }
]
```

I'm guessing it's going to look something like this?

```
  needsSorted.sort((a, b) => { 
    if(sorter.sortField...){
      return 1
  })
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if the question is silly, but if they have the same objects and you want them to be in the same order, then why not just throw one of the away and make a copy of the first? I suspect you are not telling us what you really want to do. Do you perhaps want to compare the arrays somehow?

Comment: If they had different properties, but shared that one property, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes sorry sorry!  They had different properties, but shared 1 property and were out of order.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Yeah I need to compare them for data sanitation to make sure the user didn't mess with it client side.

Comment: In that case I would go about it completely differently: sort both by the same field, then compute a hash of `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const output = [];
sortedArray.forEach( sortedItem => {
    const matchingItem = unsortedArray.find( unsortedItem => unsortedItem.sortField === sortedItem.sortField );
    if(matchingItem){
      output.push(matchingItem);
    }
});
```

Since you know the second array is the order you want the items from the first array to be in, you should loop through it. Then find the matching item from the first list, and push it into your output in that order.

Comment: Works man thanks!  I was trying to stick with a simple sort(), but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a sorting lookup that maps the sort key to the index in the original array. Then in your sort, you can look it up for both objects in the comparison.

This replaces the repeated need to lookup the index in the original array for each comparison with a constant time object lookup so it should be more performant for larger arrays at the expense of the space for the lookup object.

```js
let sortObj = [{"displayName": "Party","sortField": "com.uniqueXbd","elementId": "PtyListPanel"}, {"displayName": "Group","sortField": "com.uniqueARd","elementId": "GrpListPaneARd"}, {"displayName": "Leader","sortField": "com.uniqueEcF","elementId": "LeaderListPaneEcF"}]
let needsSorted = [{"displayName": "Group","sortField": "com.uniqueARd","elementId": "GrpListPaneARd"}, {"displayName": "Leader","sortField": "com.uniqueEcF","elementId": "LeaderListPanel"}, {"displayName": "Party","sortField": "com.uniqueXbd","elementId": "PtyListPaneEcF"}]

let sortLookup = sortObj.reduce((obj, item, idx) => {
    obj[item.sortField] = idx
    return obj
}, {})


needsSorted.sort((a,b) => sortLookup[a.sortField] - sortLookup[b.sortField])

console.log(needsSorted)
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  I was wondering if this could be done with Sort()

Answer (score -1):

```
   var obj = [
    {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 9
    }, {
        "one": 3,
        "two": 5
    }, {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2
    }
];
var obj = [
    {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2,
    }, {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 9
    }, {
        "one": 3,
        "two": 5
    }
];
obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a["one"] - b["one"] || a["two"] - b["two"];

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const sortedIndexes = sorter.map(i => i.sortField);

needsSorted.sort((a, b) => {
    const aIndex = sortedIndexes.findIndex((i) => i === a.sortField);
    const bIndex = sortedIndexes.findIndex((i) => i === b.sortField);
    return aIndex - bIndex;
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it answers the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Given that you just want to compare the two arrays and make sure they are still the same, I would go about it differently:

```js
const first = sorted.sort((a, b) => a.localCompare(b))
const second = needsSorting.sort((a, b) => a.localCompare(b))
if (JSON.stringify(first) != JSON.stringify(second)) {
  console.log("the array was modified!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const sortOrder = sorted.map(item => item.sortField);

needsSorted.sort((a, b) => {
   return sortOrder.indexOf(a.sortField) > sortOrder.indexOf(b.sortField) ? 1 : -1;
 });
```

Comment: Please also explain your answer and why it is better/different from the other anwers, which are already given.

Comment: Thank you for contributing! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
const fields = sorted.map(x => x.sortField);
const value = x => fields.indexOf(x.sortField);

needSorted.sort((a, b) => value(a) - value(b));

console.log(needSorted);
```

```js
const sorted = [
  {
    displayName: "Party",
    sortField: "com.uniqueXbd",
    elementId: "PtyListPanel"
  },
  {
    displayName: "Group",
    sortField: "com.uniqueARd",
    elementId: "GrpListPaneARd"
  },
  {
    displayName: "Leader",
    sortField: "com.uniqueEcF",
    elementId: "LeaderListPaneEcF"
  }
];

const needSorted = [
  {
    displayName: "Group",
    sortField: "com.uniqueARd",
    elementId: "GrpListPaneARd"
  },
  {
    displayName: "Leader",
    sortField: "com.uniqueEcF",
    elementId: "LeaderListPanel"
  },
  {
    displayName: "Party",
    sortField: "com.uniqueXbd",
    elementId: "PtyListPaneEcF"
  }
];

const fields = sorted.map(x => x.sortField);
const value = x => fields.indexOf(x.sortField);

needSorted.sort((a, b) => value(a) - value(b));

console.log(needSorted);
```